# Cant run matlab script from php

Tags: php, matlab

My php script executes a matlab script. A php script is simple code that opens .m file.

```
// phpcreatefile.php
$command = '/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/bin/matlab phpcreatefile.m';
proc_open($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
```

And the .m file is simple code that generates a text file with random numbers.

```
function phpcreatefile()
fid = fopen('test.txt', 'wt');
for i = 1:100
    randNumber = [num2str(rand(1)) '\n'];
    fprintf(fid, randNumber);
end
fclose(fid);
quit force
```

When I run a command `php phpcreatefile.php`, I get the following error logs.

```
Error writing to output stream.

Error writing to output stream.

Error writing to output stream.

Error writing to output stream.

{    : matlabpath
Error writing to output stream.

 : matlabrc (line 75)
        matlabpath([oldPath osPathsep matlabpath])
}
```

The matlab code itself runs fine when done in matlab application. What is causing the errors here?

Comment: why don't you use exec to execute system command?..execute matlab command using exe

Comment: Because i wasnt able to get the error output with exec. As far as i know proc_open does the same thing as of executing a command line.